# Spring boot + Gradle properties file

Tags: java, gradle

I have two properties files in `src/main/resources` `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties`.

When I run my application with `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev` it picks the correct properties file and my application is running.

However when I use `gradle -Dspring.profiles.active=dev test`, the properties are not set from the specified profile.

I also created an `application.properties` file containing `spring.profiles.active=dev`.
When I compile and run with `java -jar test.jar` it works as expected but when I use `gradle test` the properties are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There are two JVMs involved, one running Gradle and one running your test.  When you run `gradle -Dspring.profiles.active=dev test` you are setting a property on the JVM running Gradle, not the JVM running your test.  Gradle doesn't automatically copy system properties from its JVM to the JVM it spawns.  [This topi](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_should_i_be_handling_passing_system_properties_from_gradle_to_my_tests)c at the Gradle forums explains how to set properties on the JVM running your test, but in short you'll need something like this in your build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'dev test'
}
```

If you've set the active profile as a system property you can use this:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', System.getProperty('spring.profiles.active')
}
```

To copy all system properties:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  systemProperties = System.getProperties()
}
```